# Input selected in R shiny is a database, not a character vector

Tags: shiny

I'm struggling to build my first shiny app. I would like the user to select a hedge fund from a list of funds and then return a graphic with it's daily returns. Each hedge fund is on a different xts object in the environment. The graphic is not working, I got an error message: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector.

My code is really simple:

```
  titlePanel("Hedge Fund Analysis"),
  # Select input named "fund"
  selectInput('fund', 'Select a hedge fund',
              choices = c("HF1", "HF2", "HF3")),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

   output$plot <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(data = input$fund, aes(x = index(input$fund), y = coredata(input$fund))) +
       geom_line()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please post the data here also, I dont know what `HF1` and so on contains

Comment: ```set.seed(123456)
HF1 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days"))```

```set.seed(456789)
HF2 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days"))```

```set.seed(321654)
HF3 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days"))```

Comment: Sorry the code is a little messy, I couldn't do better than this

Comment: Is it possible that you use a common dataset, like iris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get()` function to access the object by name:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)

set.seed(123456) 
HF1 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days")) 

set.seed(456789) 
HF2 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days")) 

set.seed(321654) 
HF3 <- as.xts(runif(365, min = -1, max = 1), order.by = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), length = 365, by = "days"))

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hedge Fund Analysis"),
    # Select input named "fund"
    selectInput('fund', 'Select a hedge fund',
                choices = c("HF1", "HF2", "HF3")),
    plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        mydata <- get(input$fund)
        ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = index(mydata), y = coredata(mydata))) +
            geom_line()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]